# Use of Account expiry, disable and lockout in Active directory

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts

I am learning the concepts of active directory. Recently I learned the difference in Account lockout, expiry and disable. My question is all these types are doing the same thing but the purpose is different.

**For example:** Account expiry can be set as an automation process and disable can be used for immediate results and the lockout is used when the password is typed incorrectly for the certain frequency. But all these types used to prevent the user from login to the computer. I am clear with that. But my doubt is, all these types are used only for prevent the user from login or is there any other differences in these types?

Answer (score 0):

All accounts behave similarly after the change except, the only difference being that of the locked accounts. Where, the account remains locked only for a specified duration and can be ‘automatically’ unlocked upon completion of the said duration. If duration is set to 0, it will never be ‘automatically’ unlocked.

More details can be found here.

https://www.windows-active-directory.com/difference-between-disabled-expired-and-locked-account.html